# javascript extract hashtags from strings

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string received from backend, and I need to extract hashtags. The tags are written in one of these two forms

```
type 1. #World is a #good #place to #live.
type 2. #World#place#live.
```

I managed to extract from first type by : `str.replace(/#(\S*)/g`
how can i change the second format to space seperated tags as well as format one?

basically i want format two to be converted from

```
 #World#place#live.
```

to

```
 #World #place #live.
```

Comment: Try `.replace(/\b#[^\s#]+/g, " $&")`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [String.match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match), with regex `#\w+`:

```js
var str = `
type 1. #World is a #good #place to #live.
type 2. #World#place#live.`

var matches = str.match(/#\w+/g)

console.log(matches)
```

`\w+` matches any word character [a-zA-Z0-9_] more than once, so you might want to tweak that.

Once you have the matches in an array you can rearrange them to your likes.

Answer (score 1):

The pattern `#(\S*)` will match a `#` followed by 0+ times a non whitespace character in a captured group. That would match a single # as well. The string `#World#place#live.` contains no whitespace character so the whole string will be matched.

You could match them instead by using a negated character class. Match #, followed by a negated character class that matches not a # or a whitespace character.

```
#[^#\s]+
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/pDlum4/1)

```js
const strings = [
  "#World is a #good #place to #live.",
  "#World#place#live."

];
let pattern = /#[^#\s]+/g;

strings.forEach(s => {
  console.log(s.match(pattern));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

How about that using regex `/#([\w]+\b)/gm` and join by space  like below to extract `#hastags` from your string? **OR** you can use `str.replace(/\b#[^\s#]+/g, " $&")` as commented by *@Wiktor*

```js
function findHashTags(str) {  
    var regex = /#([\w]+\b)/gm;
    var matches = [];
    var match;

    while ((match = regex.exec(str))) {
        matches.push(match[0]);
    }
    return matches;
}
let str1 = "#World is a #good #place to #live."
let str2 = "#World#place#live";
let res1 = findHashTags(str1);
let res2 = findHashTags(str2);
console.log(res1.join(' '));
console.log(res2.join(' '));
```